# What does the smiley face ":)" mean in CSS?

Tags: css

I spotted this CSS code in a project:

```
html, body { :)width: 640px;}
```

I have been around with CSS for a long time now but I never saw this ":)" code before. Does it mean anything or is it just a typo?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. The developer trying to be fun, or maybe a way for him to mark areas of the code that he or she will look for?

Comment: @stijn still might be some odd vendor specific code...

Comment: @series0ne I take it you've never seen the Internet Explorer asterisk hack.

Comment: @series0ne: This looks like a parser hack. Parse errors are usually unintentional. Usually.

Comment: If this is indeed a browser hack, you'll want to add a comment in the CSS file explaining this.

Comment: “I'd like to meet the vendor that thinks it's acceptable to break free from W3C guidelines and conventions surrounding CSS.” 

That is backwards. The W3C documents what vendors do, after the fact. If this smiley face had a purpose and the browser vendors were all using it, W3C would add it to standard CSS.

Comment: @series0ne Have you ever [validated Bootstrap](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmaxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com%2Fbootstrap%2F3.2.0%2Fcss%2Fbootstrap.min.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)? You can meet the vendor at Twitter's HQ.

Comment: My guess: Code author typed :) thinking the focus was on the IM client.  When it wasn't they clicked into the IM client and proceeded from there, never realizing they'd typed a smiley in the last place their cursor was sitting, which was the CSS file.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

From an [article at javascriptkit.com](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml), that's applied for **IE 7** and earlier versions:

> if you add a non-alphanumeric character such as an asterisk (`*`) immediately before a property name, the property will be applied in IE and not in other browsers.

Also there's a hack for <= **IE 8**:

```
div {
  color: blue;      /* All browsers */
  color: purple\9;  /* IE8 and earlier */
 *color: pink;      /* IE7 and earlier */
}
```

However that's not a good idea, they don't validate. You always feel free to work with [**Conditional comments**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx) for targeting specific versions of **IE**:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie-8.css"><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie-7.css"><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie-6.css"><![endif]-->
```

But for those wanna see the hack in real, please open up [this page](http://forooma.com/test.html) in the latest version of IE you have. Then go to developer mode by doing a <kbd>F12</kbd>. In Emulation section (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>) change document mode to `7` and see what happens.

[image]

*The property used in the page is `:)font-size: 50px;`.*

Comment: i knew about "_" and "*" before the selector, but not this one you said.

Comment: @vlrprbttst Those are conventional characters used for the ease. However it concludes all non-alphanumeric values.

Comment: @revo `*` and `_` are not just conventional, the IE CSS parsers change from version to version and you can use different similar hacks to target different versions of IE.  I think those are just the most generic for "all IE". (we use a different method of targeting IEs, and have never needed the hacks, so I don't have the specifics memorized)

Comment: I may be stupid enough to miss something here, but why can he do it using 2 characters? It says "add a non-alphanumeric", not "add one or more...". Or does the `:` mean something else? Otherwise, can't I put `*********************font-size: "150%";`, etc.?

Comment: @Max You can, indeed, do that. It's not a good idea, obviously. Using a smiley is not great either IMO. Modern browsers treat those characters as invalid, IE7 tries to ignore them and render anyway. It's about abusing a strange feature of IE7 rather than something to do with modern browsers.

Comment: Just to throw an extra part to this answer. The answer is great and correct, but missing this the fact that this is not best practice. As a general rule, you should do your best to give the best experience in all browsers that your user base is using. Not to mention, in my opinion, you shouldn't support browsers that the company that made them don't support anymore.

Comment: @AlienDev, you've made two contradictory statements. "you should...give the best experience in all browsers that your user base is using" and "...IMO, you shouldn't support browsers that the company... doesn't support anymore."  Just because they aren't supported doesn't mean your user base isn't using them.

Comment: http://forooma.com/test.html link appears to refer to a domain that no longer exists. That, or my ISP is blocking access to it.

Answer (score 173):

It looks like a CSS hack to target IE7 and earlier browsers. While this ***is*** invalid CSS and browsers should ignore it, IE7 and earlier will parse and honor this rule. Here is an example of this hack in action:

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: url(background.png);
    :)background: url(why-you-little.png);
}
```

**IE8 (ignores the rule)**

[image: Example 1 - IE8]

**IE7 (applies the rule)**

[image: Example 1 - IE7]

Note that it does not have to be a smiley face; [**BrowserHacks**](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-6d49e92634f26ae6d6e46b3ebc10019a) mentions:

> Any combination of these characters:
>   **`` ! $ & * ( ) = % + @ , . / ` [ ] # ~ ? : < > | ``**
>   [before the property name will work on] Internet Explorer ≤ 7

---

[The GAH hot dog stand example is here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25444514/4).

Comment: Yeah, from IE8 and upward IE considers itself to be CSS compliant and is bit by bit breaking all their IE specific css fixes. (so hence we need to resort to javascript solutions)

Comment: @ikkuh To be fair, IE11 is a fairly decent and compliant browser. There's a reason they dropped support for IE conditional comments in it.

Comment: @apj15243 Yeah they have come a long way and hope they will keep on going, truth is that I still need conditional support for it, and that is not only IE11, but also 10,9 and 8. So let's wish for an auto-update as well, there is no reason to not run IE11 on XP other than commercial reasons. But thats a different discussion.